# How to change a bash variable in a configuration file?

Tags: bash

I want to be able to change a variable in a source file from inside of a bash script. I have the following two files:

**conf.dat**

```
variable=1
```

**file.sh**

```
source conf.dat

cat conf.dat

echo $variable

variable=2

cat conf.dat
```

When I execute this (`./file.sh`), I get the following output:

```
variable=1
1
variable=1
```

When I changed the variable inside of `file.sh`, it does not back propagate into the source `conf.dat`. Is there a way to change the variable in `conf.dat` from `file.sh`?

Comment: `printf 'variable=%q\n' "$variable" >conf.dat`

Comment: ...though generally, `source`ing a file that's writable by your process should be done only with care (it means you trust the process enough to modify its own code, which from a security perspective is a level of trust you should avoid giving out unnecessarily). Typically it's safer _not_ to source your data files, but to parse them instead (`printf '%s' "$variable" >conf.dat` / `variable=$(<conf.dat)`, for example).